# Unzip and overwrite if file exists

Tags: c#, zip

What I want to do is unzip file into an existing directory and overwrite older file if it exists.

I am using this command to unzip file:

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(path + file_name_zip, path);
```

Comment: You forgot to ask your question!

Comment: What is the class 'ZipFile'? Is it a system class or a custom one?

Comment: ZipFile is in System.IO.Compression. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485723(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485718.aspx)

`Extracts an entry in the zip archive to a file, and optionally overwrites an existing file that has the same name.`

```
foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName), true);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thank you thats the solution!